# UnknownHostException in socket

Tags: java, sockets, runtime-error

I'm making a program that reads html from a website and pulls some things from the html. When I try to start my socket I get the UnknownHostException error. It happens when I call the InetAdress method as well. I've tried multiple ways of doing this including not using the inetaddress method and it doesn't help anything. Here's what the code looks like

```
try {
    InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName(text);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) { 

}

try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(text,80); 
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); 
}
```

Comment: Post what is `text`... Also, why do you need the InetAddress.getByName() call?

Comment: What is the value of text ??

Comment: from a command line, can you ping the host you're trying to connect to?

Comment: text is the url from the user and I used inetaddress to try to see if it changed the error

Comment: @RileyBurris are you printing out the user input before attempting to make a socket connection, cause UnknownHostException seems clear enough (I means the hostname cannot be resolved)

Comment: no, we know what `text` is supposed to mean.  But give us an example of a specific value of `text` that results in the `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV:_Oblivion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're passing just the hostname, and not the complete path to the resource you're trying to fetch.  For instance, in your comment you wrote `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV:_Oblivion` ; to determine the host your `Socket` should connect to, pass just `en.wikipedia.org` to the `InetAddress.getByName()` method.

Comment: I can't find the answer to this question i have...

Where do you then specify the path for the socket to connect to?
I read that is done in the handshake part of the connection, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Sockets are for connecting to a specific TCP or UDP host and port.  that's all.  Sockets know nothing about paths, because TCP/UDP have no concept of paths.  Higher-level protocols like HTTP, FTP, etc. deal with paths.

Comment: I see, so the "sockets" that are aware of paths are WebSockets which are built on sockets with understanding of their own standard for communication right?